# How can I pass a Vec<u8> via chain extension to pallet?

Tags: ink, wasm, chain-extension, rmrk

I am working on chain extension to call rmrk pallet methods. One of the methods needs a BoundedVec that I need to pass via ink smart contract. What data type can I use to do this on smart contract side? Is there a BoundedVec<> type on ink?

I tried using Vec and then trying to convert it to BoundedVec in the chain extension in runtime but I get the following error

```
env.read_as()?;
      |                                                                                                
      ^^^^^^^ the trait `MaxEncodedLen` is not implemented for `sp_runtime::sp_application_crypto::Vec<u8>
```

The method signature on ink contract

```
fn create_collection(contract_address: AccountId, metadata: Vec<u8>, symbol: Vec<u8>) -> Result<CollectionId, RCError>;
```

Reading the arguments in the runtime

```
let (contract_address, metadata, symbol) : (AccountId, Vec<u8>, Vec<u8>) = env.read_as()?;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can only use [`read_as()`](https://crates.parity.io/pallet_contracts/chain_extension/struct.Environment.html#method.read_as) for types whose size is known at compile time (thus the
requirement that types implement [`MaxEncodedLen`](https://crates.parity.io/frame_support/pallet_prelude/trait.MaxEncodedLen.html)).

If you don't know the size ahead of time, like in the case of a Vec, you can use
[`read_as_unbounded()`](https://crates.parity.io/pallet_contracts/chain_extension/struct.Environment.html#method.read_as_unbounded). In order to get the number of bytes to read you can use the
[`in_len()`](https://crates.parity.io/pallet_contracts/chain_extension/struct.Environment.html#method.in_len) method.

So your code would look something like:

```rust
let (contract_address, metadata, symbol): (AccountId, Vec<u8>, Vec<u8>)
    = env.read_as_unbounded(env.in_len())?;
```

I have some demo code [here](https://github.com/HCastano/decoded-2022-demo/blob/493edc950d9e7af03c8f021919f15bfc9f7e1e94/runtime/src/chain_extension.rs#L104) if you need more resources on how to implement chain-extensions.

Comment: This is awesome. Its exactly what I needed. Do you have a video recording of the demo as well somewhere?

Comment: Yeah I have a recording. It'll be uploaded to YouTube in the next few days :)

Comment: @TheDuck here is the video: https://youtu.be/yykPQF0tkqk